# Ionic dynamic component creation?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Is there a way using Ionic to dynamically create a component? For example, I have a few pages where a login prompt should be displayed. I have my component added to my module but don't know where I should go next in order to get this to display when certain events are called.

Any help as to where I should go now, I'm super confused on what I should do.

Comment: Can you show the `code` what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two options:

1. Show a new page using ionic tabs, modal, or push and put social login control on all of them.
2. Use a single component, and put each page that you wanna show in an Ionic [slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/) or `div`, and then only show the page that is relevant (using `slideTo` for slides or `*ngIf` for `div`). The social login can be added outside of the slides/div so it would be visible in all pages. You can put it in a [footer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Footer/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the **LoginPage** added to your module. You can use **Ionic** built-in `ModalController` to popup your login page everywhere you need it.

Here is an example:

```
export class MyPage {
    constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    }

    presentModal() {
        let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(LoginPage);
        modal.present();
    }
}
```

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#modals

Comment: I could do that but I'm using Mobiscroll so I want to display the Social Login each time someone needs to login.